# Why PhoneAuthProvider is unresolved for iOS and Swift even after importing

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, authentication

I have successfully installed Firebase into my iOS project by following official guidelines, and now want to test out phone authentication that was already accomplished successfully for the other phone OS platform. The issue is the function

```
PhoneAuthProvider.provider().verifyPhoneNumber(phoneNumber, uiDelegate:...
```

It gives a red exclamation error telling

```
Use of unresolved identifier 'PhoneAuthProvider'
```

This even after updating the Pod file with

```
pod 'Firebase'
pod 'Firebase/Core'
pod 'Firebase/Auth'
~ pod install
~ open myproj.xcworkspace
```

Now in the ViewController.swift I import the firebase

```
import Firebase
```

Of course the import and checks with .plist file were already done and I could already successfully connect prior to this. The AppDelegate has required initialization as well. I'm stumbled in this particular place where a required class is not being able to be resolved.

Help!

Comment: you can try Auth.provider()

Comment: @SagarBhut Is it an official alternative or why should I steer away from what Apple tells me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, so I found the solution myself. The following were the steps

First I had to create a fresh project with all new dependencies and IDs and a new plist file in the Firebase console.

Second I had to create pod file differently. I wonder what I did before, but this is what you have to do

```
pod 'Firebase/Core'
```

inside the file after creating it with

```
:~$ pod init
```

Now, save the file and in the terminal

```
:~$ pod install
```

Now I run the app and let Firebase know I have configured the plist correctly.

Then when I have to use the phone authentication enabled, I had to go through this https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/ios/phone-auth

Basically I now insert new line

```
pod 'Firebase/Auth'
```

and then issue

```
:~$ pod install
```

After successfully running the workspace, I was able to import simply the Firebase lib on top and call the function wherever I could without the red exclamation error. However I still am bugged with a trivial issue. The line

```
self.showMessagePrompt()
```

is undefined and now throws an error. I had to suppress it by commenting it out and issuing a simple log to the console.